# random user can access mysql db

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I'm writing an app on python and MySQL(MySQLdb, PyQT) and an faced an issue. 
I so happened that when a random value entered on login form this random user have some access to the db. This user cannot use SELECT but he can use INSERT!
I am new to MySQL and it's the first time I face such an issue. I saw the question like the one I'm asking but there a random user was able to login to db but had not rights to do anything. 
I've looked into MYSQL.user table and users without user names had no rights to manipulate data. the out put is like follows

```
| localhost                | root             | Y           | Y           | Y               |
| 127.0.0.1                | root             | Y           | Y           | Y           |
| localhost                |                  | N           | N           | N           |
......
```

Can someone suggest why is it so happened and is there a solution (workaround?)?

Comment: I imagine this has to do with the database permissions you set up on mysql not mysqldb

Comment: My guess is that you need to control access on the python side.  How do you construct your connection string?  Please tell me you aren't creating a mysql user for each of your app users.

Comment: Thank you. My bad, I really wanted to create different app users as different db users. But still even if I create a set of tables for access control it won't solve the root of issue. Every one will be able edit these user tables via command shell. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use mysql's access permissions?

Comment: Could you please provide an example? As I shown in the listing above the user without the username doesn't have any permissions at all ('N') but can use INSERT. May be you are talking about different permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,ofcourse there is a solution in mysql for your problem.

Use GRANT and REVOKE to do so,these lies under DATA CONTROL LANGUAGE in SQL.

I giving an example how to use it..

```
mysql> revoke all privileges on *.* from 'root'@'localhost';
```

Using this query I revoked all the privileges of root user on all the tables of all databases.
If I want this in case of any particular database then..

```
mysql> revoke all privileges on exampledatabase.* from 'root'@'localhost';
```

If I want this in case of any particular table then..

```
mysql> revoke all privileges on exampledatabase.mytable from 'root'@'localhost';
```

If I want to restrict a particular privilege in case of any particular table then..

```
mysql> revoke select on exampledatabase.mytable from 'root'@'localhost';
```

Now I want to grant a particular privilege to the root user in case of an particular table then..

```
mysql> grant select on exampledatabase.mytable
   to 'root'@'localhost' identified by password
   '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF' with grant option ;
```

Comment: I suggest using some other user name other than root in your examples.